# In the USA, are there more African American men in prison than in college?

Tags: united-states, race, criminology

I read in a book that "as the next millennium begins, there are more young black men in prison than in college." Jury Nullification by Clay S Conrad (Kindle edition, Dec 2013 loc: 343). (First Published 1998)

Thinking "That's awful and really?" I first turned to google.

http://www.acenet.edu/the-presidency/columns-and-features/Pages/By-the-Numbers-More-Black-Men-in-Prison-Than-in-College-Think-Again-.aspx

provides a statistical table for 2000-2010 indicating that there were more African Americans in college than in jail or prison in the year 2002 and thereafter. But in 2000 and 2001, there were more in jail or prison.

The same article notes that:

> A Washington Post editorial published in June referenced a 2007 quote
>   from then-Senator Barack Obama. In this quote, Obama stated that “we
>   have more black men in prison than we have in our colleges.”

National Public Radio (NPR, a non-profit broadcaster) has published a [transcript of a radio program](http://www.npr.org/2013/04/23/178601467/are-there-really-more-black-men-in-prison-than-college) dated April 23, 2013:

> But you've probably heard that there are more African-American men in
>   jail than in college. Even then-candidate Barack Obama talked about
>   this at an NAACP candidate forum, back in 2007.
>
> (SOUNDBITE OF ARCHIVED RECORDING)
>
> PRESIDENT BARACK OBAMA: We have more work to do when more young black
>   men languish in prison than attend colleges and universities across
>   America.
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Ivory Toldson is an associate professor at Howard University School of
>   Education. He wrote about this for TheRoot.com, and he says...
>
> IVORY TOLDSON: It's wrong. There are 1.4 million black men in college
>   right now, and there are about 840,000 black men in prison.

An [NBC News article from Sep 2007](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/21001543/#.UrPfOt9OXoc) suggests the results can vary depending on who is included in the college category:

> More than three times as many black people live in prison cells as in
>   college dorms, the government said in a report to be released
>   Thursday. The ratio is only slightly better for Hispanics at 2.7
>   inmates for every Latino in college housing. Among non-Hispanic
>   whites, more than twice as many live in college housing as in prison
>   or jail. The numbers, driven by men, do not include college students
>   who live off campus.  Previously released census data show that black
>   and Hispanic college students — commuters and those in dorms — far
>   outnumber black and Hispanic prison inmates.

Obviously this topic is something of a political football. I would be open to editorial suggestions to further pin down the question.

Comment: Coming from a non-US country, the difference in numbers between attending a college/university and living in a college dorm is immense. (My estimate: <10% of student live on campus here.) I understand that this is somewhat different in parts of the USA. (This is a cultural difference that bewilders me.) I wonder how important that is to the estimates.

Comment: @Oddthinking Depends on the age of the student and the school. Some require all freshman under a certain age to live on campus and others require it of all undergraduate students. Location also plays a big role as well, personally I would dismiss any comments that involve students living in dorms as "Yes, so what?" since living on campus or not doesn't really mean anything meaningful versus actually being enrolled at a school.

Comment: @rob: I understood (and remain culturally bewildered by) the first half of your comment. Wasn't clear on the second - are you saying the two populations sizes are actually close enough to treat as the same, and I need not be concerned?

Comment: @Oddthinking No, I think that the number of students enrolled is a more meaningful measure than the number of enrolled students living in the dorms. There are too many other factors involved in why a student may or may not be living in the dorms to make meaningful comparisons.

Comment: I agree that students living in the dorms is not a particularly meaningful measurement. I attend a university in a relatively conservative area of the U.S. and only 26% of the students live on campus with the majority of those being freshmen.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Right now, the answer is no, though in 2007 when Obama made the claim the answer was yes.  In both cases the numbers are very close.

Data on the number of male African Americans in Federal, state, and local prisons and jails are available from the Bureau of Justice statistics [here](http://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/pim09st.pdf)

Data on the number of male African Americans enrolled in college are available from the US Census Bureau [here](http://www.census.gov/compendia/statab/2012/tables/12s0279.pdf)

They each contain the values for a number of recent years, which I have listed below.  Up until 2006 there were more African American men in prison than enrolled in college.  Since then, the reverse has been true - primarily because the college numbers have risen significantly.

|  | Prisoners | College Students | Prisoners per 100 Students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 791,600 | 635,300 | 125 |
| 2005 | 806,200 | 774,100 | 104 |
| 2006 | 836,800 | 795,400 | 105 |
| 2007 | 814,700 | 838,100 | 97 |
| 2008 | 846,000 | 911,800 | 93 |
| 2009 | 841,200 | 1,037,100 | 81 |

The data are available for white men as well, and the equivalent values are strikingly different:

|  | Prisoners | College Students | Prisoners per 100 Students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 663,700 | 4,634,600 | 14 |
| 2005 | 688,700 | 5,007,200 | 14 |
| 2006 | 718,100 | 5,046,200 | 14 |
| 2007 | 755,500 | 5,146,100 | 15 |
| 2008 | 712,500 | 5,302,900 | 13 |
| 2009 | 693,800 | 5,594,400 | 12 |

Comment: It's important to note that, at the time the claims in question were made (2000, 2007), the most recent data that would have been available would have made the statements accurate. The NPR quotation from the question is particularly problematic, as it uses 2013 data to 'refute' a soundbite form 2007, which was most likely based on information from 2006, which, this answer demonstrates, would have made that soundbite accurate.

Comment: It is pretty clear that the change in number of college students accounts for the change in ratio: the prisoners presumably weren't going anywhere, while the number of African Americans in college soared. I guess college keeps people out of prison. Maybe they like it better there.

Comment: Can you go to college while in prison? That would probably be very useful to make prisoners not return to jail.

Comment: Mark, your census link is broken and if you look at this 2007 census data https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2007/demo/school-enrollment/2007-cps.html you'll see over 1 million Black males were enrolled in college, which is much different from your answer.

Comment: @gnasher729 Any form of "Can you go to <X> while in prison?" might make prisoners not return to jail, esp if <X> is far away from the prison  ;)

Comment: Notably, the prison : student ratio seems to be awfully high *internationally* even without the racial differences. A quick glance at first Google results for recent numbers in Germany comes up with some [46,000](https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/72216/umfrage/gefangene-und-verwahrte-in-justizvollzugsanstalten-nach-bundeslaendern/)  prisoners vs. [2,900,000](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Presse/Pressemitteilungen/2020/12/PD20_497_213.html) students or less than 2 prisoners per 100 students (though admittedly comparability of definitions of "prisoner", "student" needs to be checked)

Comment: @gnasher729 There are some programs that allow inmates to enroll in college classes (referred to as "Prison Education" and usually via correspondence or online), but the programs tend to be fairly limited and unlikely to really swing the numbers that much.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The US has an incarceration rate of 698 per 100,000 residents, so these numbers seem about right.  Some rough google searches show about 19.7 million full and part time students ([source](https://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=372)) and 2.3 million incarcerated ([source](https://www.prisonpolicy.org/reports/pie2020.html)) or about 11.6 inmates per 100 students.

Comment: @DavePhD According to the link you provided, only 789k Black Males were enrolled in college at all levels in 2007 in the USA. The 1.6million figure appears to be for both sexes. That would push the ratio back into true claim territory.

Comment: @GOATNine that's not what I see.  https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/demo/tables/school-enrollment/2007/2007-cps/tab01-04.xls It says 1,016,000 purely-Black males are enrolled, excluding those who are institutionalized and excluding those in the military.  Then there is a separate table for all Blacks, including mixed race people like Obama, and that has an even higher number.

Comment: It may be the change in college students that makes the difference, but the scary number is the prisoners. There are about 5 times as many whites as blacks in the USA, and between 7 to five times as many whites as blacks in college. But more blacks in prison than whites. So about five times as many as we would expect.

Comment: @DavePhD I realized where the hole in the data came from. Table 5 has the categories split between full time and part time enrollment, I was only looking at full time. That being said, the data is for 2007, where the data available for the claim would have been 2006, which would have made the claim correct at the time of utterance.

Comment: There seem to be important omissions in this answer: 1. It conflates "black **men**" (18 and older), the term used in the question, with "black **males**" (of any age). This is probably minor (no pun intended), since juveniles are presumably a very small (but nonzero) fraction of both college students and the incarcerated.

Comment: 2. More significantly, two of the quotes in the question specify that the comparison is not simply for black men, but for "**young** black men". While there is no standard definition of "young", it certainly has the potential to change the comparison, since *virtually all* college students would qualify as young, whereas a significant fraction of incarcerated people are *middle-aged and older*.

Comment: @nanoman. The complete question, as asked, is not consistent with respect to age.  The title says "men".  The first paragraph says "young men".  The text of the link in the third paragraph says "men".  The first quote from NPR says "men".  The NPR quote from then-Senator Obama says "young black men".  The quote from Ivory Toldson says "men".  The NBC news article says "black people".  
I don't think it's at all clear that the question is specifically asking about "young black men" or simply "black men".  If it really is just one or the other, then which one is it?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the question is inconsistent. I'm suggesting that an ideal answer, rather than silently picking one interpretation of the claim to analyze, would note the ambiguity and explain whether one version could be true while a seemingly slight rephrasing could be false. Moreover, the interpretation you picked seems to be one that is *not* present in any of the question's quotes: "male" (including juveniles as well as adults -- which you used to look up government statistics) is a new category in your answer that is not used in the question.